# debian 9 - Hook on poweroff, not on reboot?

Tags: linux, debian, reboot

I have a WiFi power socket which powers one of my debian boxes. Now, when shutting down, I want to send a message (MQTT, curl, whatever) to my home automation server, so that the power socket gets turned off with a small delay. But only on poweroff, NOT on reboot.

I read several threads, but what I found did not really help me.

So what I would need is how/where to place a script that is just called on poweroff, not on reboot....
*bump*